# How can i get a checked Checkbox title value in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to get chekbox title value. How can i do that ?

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSingle" runat="server" onclick="Checked(this);" title='<%#Eval("CarServiceFormInvoiceRecordID") %>' />
```

My func doesn't work..

```
function Checked(cb) {
            if (cb.checked) {
                alert(cb.title);
...
```

Comment: use `cb.getAttribute('title')`

Comment: @TamilSelvan How is this different from OP using cb.title?

Comment: @Ted How is this different from OP using cb.checked?

Comment: "My func doesn't work." Which means? Any error or what?

Comment: Just test with: title="mytitle"   What returns alert(cb.title)?

Comment: @roasted you right...`cb.title` also work fine..

Comment: Maybe `<asp:Checkbox />` will change the `title` attribute to `<label />` tag.

Comment: @TamilSelvan ya, because internally getAttribute('title') call property title of DOM object, it's just slower to use getAttribute()

Comment: @roasted alert(cb.title) alert is empty

Comment: @Ahmet alert() empty for title="mytitle" (hard coded)? Of course you have removed title='<%#Eval("CarServiceFormInvoiceRecordID") %>'  right?

Comment: title="mytitle" 
alert($('#chkSingle').attr('title')); >> undefined 
alert(cb.title); >> alert is empty {no value}

Comment: Thats really strange! Is your element #chkSingle unique on context page? What give you alert($('#chkSingle').length); ?

Comment: @roasted `$('#chkSingle').length` will return `0` actually, because ASP.NET will change it, except when using `ClientIDMode="Static"` in the `<asp:Checkbox />` controller. However, the function is not rely on the ID...

Comment: @NOX Ok, i don't use ASP, that's why i was not aware of, thx for input :)

Comment: Can you show us the **GENERATED** code of your `<asp:Checkbox />`?

Comment: madness.. i cant get the title value

Comment: <input id="chkSingle" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$c1$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl04$chkSingle" onclick="Checked(this);">

Comment: @NOX why doesn't show title property in the GENERATED code ?

Comment: @Ahmet This is the **PROBLEM**! I'm trying to find out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on these comments:

> **[NOX]** - Can you show us the GENERATED code of your ?
>   **[Ahmet]** - `<input id="chkSingle" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$c1$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl04$chkSingle" onclick="Checked(this);">`

The `title` attribute is not generated in the output. Why? I don't know really. Let's check it step by step.

First, change your checkbox to this one:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSingle" runat="server" onclick="Checked(this);" title='HELLO' />
```

As you see, I changed the value of `title` attribute. Check the output, if you haven't any `title` attribute, try to change it to something like `data-title`:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSingle" runat="server" onclick="Checked(this);" data-title='HELLO' />
```

Now check your generated code, it must be something like this (I hope so):

```
<input id="chkSingle" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$c1$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl04$chkSingle" onclick="Checked(this);" data-title="Hello">
```

If in generated code, the attribute `data-title` is exists, then you succeed.
Now you must change your function to get this attribute:

```
alert(cb.getAttribute('data-title'));
```

---

### UPDATE

As you comment, the generated code is:

```
<span data-title="HELLO"><input id="ctl00_c1_RadGrid1_ctl00_ctl04_chkSingle" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$c1$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl04$chkSingle" onclick="Checked(this);" /></span>
```

So, the attribute you attach to the `<asp:Checkbox />` became to an `span` tag. So you must change your function to something like this:

```
function Checked(cb) {
    var $input = $(cb);
    var $span = $input.closest('span');
    var title = $span.attr('data-title');

    if ($input.is(':checked')) {
        alert(title);
    }
}
```

- Check the **[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L2snP/)**.
- I think you can put back `data-title` to `title` attribute again.

Comment: Thank you ! But i can't get the data-title value because generated code is <span data-title="HELLO"><input id="ctl00_c1_RadGrid1_ctl00_ctl04_chkSingle" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$c1$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl04$chkSingle" onclick="Checked(this);" /></span>

How can i get span value ?

Comment: @Ahmet Thanks you can use jQuery in your project, check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2snP/).

Comment: You are King.. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
$('#chkSingle').attr('title')
```

to ensure that checkbox is checked

```
$('#chkSingle[type="checkbox"]').filter(function(){return $(this).is(':checked')}).attr('tile')
```

Comment: How is this different from OP using cb.title? BTW, using property title is still better

Comment: The `ID` attribute inside ASP Web Controls, isn't exactly what you get in your HTML output, so your selector (`$('#chkSingle')`) will always return an empty matched set.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery:

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
  alert($(this).attr('title'));
}
```

Javascript:

change you call from `Checked(this);` to `Checked(this.id);`

and you function to:

```
function Checked(checkId) {
  var checkbox = document.getElementById(checkId);
  if(checkbox.checked) {
    alert(checkId);
    ....
```

Sorry, getting caught up with some of the comments here, I oversaw your actual problem. You need to have a look at the markup generated and see how the label for the checkbox is generated. Paste it here and I'll tell you how to access the value.

Comment: No, why use jquery when js expose natively properties?

Comment: @roasted - I assumed he wanted a jquery solution due to the jquery tag.

Comment: I see a javascript tag too. BTW, why making code slower using jquery when you can access direct property using js?

Comment: @roasted - added a javascript solution, too. hope you're happy now

Comment: i don't think the problem come from here, i think OP is doing something wrong somewhere else. But ya, i'm happy when not seeing useless jquery code :) {i don't mean your previous answer was useless}

Comment: Sorry, getting caught up with some of the comments here, I oversaw your actual problem. You need to have a look at the markup generated and see how the label for the checkbox is generated. Paste it here and I'll tell you how to access the value.

Answer (score 0):

you may try like this

```
function Checked(cb) {
            if (cb.checked) {
                alert(cb.getAttribute('title'));
   }
}
```

Comment: How is this different from OP using cb.title?

Answer (score 0):

you may try like that ::

```
$(':checked').prop('title', function(k) {
        tit[k]= $(this).attr('title');
    });
```